# Why await is not allowed in a finally block?

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

Why `await` is not allowed in a `finally` block?

```
public async void Fn()
{
    try
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        await Task.Delay(4000);
    }
}
```

knowing that it is possible to get the `Awaiter` manually

```
public void Fn()
{
    try
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        var awaiter = Task.Delay(4000).GetAwaiter();
     }
}
```

Comment: Have you read Eric Lippert's blog post about no yields in finally blocks? Many of the same points apply: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/16/iterator-blocks-part-three-why-no-yield-in-finally.aspx

Comment: just guesswork here: maybe it is because try...finally and await happen in different compiler steps and they do not compose well?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Taken from: [*Where can’t I use “await”?*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx#14)

> Inside of a catch or finally block. You can use “await” inside of a
>   try block, regardless of whether it has associated catch or finally
>   blocks, but you can’t use it inside of the catch or finally blocks.
>   **Doing so would disrupt the semantics of CLR exception handling.**

**This is apparently no longer true in C# 6.0**

Taken from: [*A C# 6.0 Language Preview*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn683793.aspx)

> C# 6.0 does away with this deficiency, and now allows await calls within both catch and finally blocks (they were already supported in try blocks)